# adjoint representation of 2-Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, higher-category-theory, lie-groupoids

Baez and Crans in their paper on Lie 2-algebras refer to adjoint representations of Lie 2-groups but don't say much, as far as I can tell, except to say that such a representation acts on a 2-Lie algebra.  Where can I find a description of the adjoint representation of Lie 2-groups?

Is there any connection with representations of Lie groupoids up to homotopy?

Comment: I guess Baez and Crans say "Lie 2-algebras," so I have edited the question.   I couldn't find the definition of an adjoint representation in the http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409602, just a brief comment that it exists and no reference.  That's one of the reasons for posing the question.

Comment: See also page 6 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6225v1.pdf on the adjoint representation.

Comment: p. 6 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6225v1.pdf talks about adjoint representations of Lie 2-algebras not of  Lie 2-groups.

Comment: I had once thought on this. IMHO, there is no adjoint representation of Lie 2-groups unless for strict Lie 2-groups (cross module).

Comment: @Ma Ming So what's the adjoint rep of Lie crossed modules?